# Drivers related to audio device and the relation to their sound quality

Tags: audio, windows-8

I've come across a suprising problem. I just plugged a USB headset to my laptop and started recording some voices using audacity. This was very noisy and not just the ambient noise but noise of tweaks from the microphone.
But, when I use skype's echo testing service, to my big surprise, the same voice,(with no greater loudness that I had recorded earlier with), is crystal clear.
I tested both samples at my own room, using the same headset.(since I wanted to record my voice), I can't use skype's testing service to do recording, I wanted to know if there were any other other programs where I could record and be able to actually output the recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few commercial denoise plugins (e.g. WNS) for DAW software, but Audacity has also built-in denoise function (filter/effect to use after recording).

Comment: that did it, I didn't use much of audacity so I didn't know

Answer (score 3):

You can record sounds using [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) from the command line.

[Here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Windows) are some examples of capture with FFMPEG on Windows operating system.

To list your input devices:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

To record from microphone:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone" output.wav
```

Bonus: another [tutorial](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow)!

Comment: do you happen to know something about the "skype" thing I mentioned above? Like it's because of it's algorithm or something?

Comment: It's hard to figure out the origin of the problem out of the blue... maybe Skype and Audacity use different input, configure them differently, process it differently... What happens when you record with FFMPEG?

Comment: cmd says it doesn't recognize the command ffmpeg

Comment: You need to install it first ([download page is here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)), and either run it from the directory in which the binaries are, or set the given directory in your [PATH environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: thanks, that worked as well, though I had already marked the above